# Asynchronous and parallel-processing. Sleeping in methods

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, parallel-processing

Given 10 images, and a team, for example, of 2 people. The first processes the image in 1 minute, the second in 2. How long does it take to process?

I create two persons, with lower values, in seconds. And I call the process method.

You need to call two methods for different objects in parallel. The first works faster than the second. A general variable with the number of images is available, which changes after processing by one or another stream.

Nothing works, of course. I tried `.WhenAll`, it did not work.

That should be around 7.5 seconds, not 14.
[image: Screen]

Main:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Test.Controller;
using Test.View;
using Test.Model;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person person1 = new Person(1000);
            Person person2 = new Person(2000);

            List<Person> people = new List<Person> { person1, person2 };

            int images_amount = 10;
            int time_processing = await ProcessingImages.ExecuteAsync(images_amount, people);

            TimeProcessing.TimeExecute(time_processing);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Test.Model;

namespace Test.Controller
{
    class ProcessingImages
    {
        static async public Task<int> ExecuteAsync(int images_amount, List<Person> people, int time_processing = 0)
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

            foreach (Person p in people)
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => Execute(ref images_amount, p.Speed)));
            }
            await Task<int>.WhenAll(tasks);

            foreach (Task<int> task in tasks)
            {
                time_processing += await task;
            }
            return time_processing;
        }

        static private int Execute(ref int images_amount, int seconds_per_image, int count = 0)
        {
            while (images_amount > 0)
            {
                images_amount--;
                count += seconds_per_image;
                Console.WriteLine("Start thread " + seconds_per_image);
                Thread.Sleep(seconds_per_image);
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
using System;

namespace Test.View
{
    class TimeProcessing
    {
        static public void TimeExecute(int time_processing)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Total time processing: {0} seconds", time_processing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your question is, and you don't seem to have included all of the code necessary for a [mcve].

Comment: Also, why are you using `Task.Run` to call `Execute` instead of just making that function itself `async` or return a `Task`?

Comment: @Herohtar I don't know.

Comment: in your output should be 20 logs `Start thread ...` because you call those tasks 2 times. First when you run `.WhenAll(tasks)` and second time is when you iterate through the collection and await each task to execute again. Are you aware about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just measuring wrong. You're adding up the time that you told each thread to delay, not the real-world time from when the first one started to when the last one finished.

If you use a [`Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8) to actually time how long it takes, it's about 7 seconds:

```
var watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();

int time_processing = await ProcessingImages.ExecuteAsync(images_amount, people);

watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Total time processing: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```